# What is the Simple way to use URL params in react-router V6

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am learning to react and the tutorial was way too old so I switched to documentation and articles. But I found it very confusing. (Eg: Switch was removed in V6 But still there in V6 docs).

How to use URL params to render a param to an element? like a heading?

Answer (score 1):

you can use this `let {id} = useParams();` for a route with a following path `path="/manage-business/:id"`

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you install react router dom

   `npm install react-router-dom`
2. import react router

   `import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'`;
3. Wrap your components in the Router and Routes imports. This is a must for v6.

   ```
       <Router>
       <Routes>
           <Route
               exact
               path="/any-name"
               element={(<componentNameToShow />)}
           />                                           
       </Routes>                                        
       </Router>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Michal Šajdík ans

```
export function Some() {
    let { name } = useParams(); 
    return (
        <div>
        <p>All details about {name}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

and in your App.js

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="link/:name" element={<Some/>} />
          </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
```